# Keep modal and showing errors after validation with Laravel 4 + 3 Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, modal-dialog, validation

Reading the article: [`Keep modal open after validation redirect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751734/keep-modal-open-after-validation-redirect)
enable to open the modal box right after validation, however, shows no errors occurred, shows only the form, I believe it is because the action is calling the jquery form again, because I'm using the remote function bootstrap 3 modal.

tips to solve and please show errors in the modal window.

Controller:

```
if ($validacao->fails()) :
   $input = Input::all();
   $input['autoOpenModal'] = true;
   return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validacao)->withInput($input);
endif;
```

Modal Form:

```
<div>
   {{ Form::label( 'inputEmail1', 'Email', array( 'class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label' ) ) }}
   <div>
      {{ Form::email( 'email', '', array( 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Email' ) ) }}
      {{ $errors->first('email', '<p class="help-block text-danger">:message</p>') }}
   </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if ({{ Input::old('autoOpenModal', 'false') }}) {
      $('#remoteModal').modal({show: true, remote: '{{ URL::to('users/inserir') }}'});
   }
</script>
```

I think this remote is loading the bootstrap modal like a new call therefore his `$errors->first()` is not showing anything.

thanks for the help already

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any remote fetching here. The form already exists on the page, in the modal.

As your post you are following says:

```
    if ({{ Input::old('autoOpenModal', 'false') }}) {
        //JavaScript code that open up your modal.
        $('#remoteModal').modal('show');
    }
```